# AfterAll hook error - 'this' is not referring to my world constructor when using cucumber-js and selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumberjs

I am getting 'AfterAll hook errored' when attempting to close my browser at the end of my tests (using cucumber-js and selenium). 'this' is not referring to world as it does in my step.js files

This is my hooks.js file:

```
const { AfterAll, Before } = require("cucumber");

AfterAll(async function() {
  await this.browser.close();
});
```

and this is my world.js file:

```
const driver = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");
const browser = new driver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
const { setWorldConstructor, setDefaultTimeout } = require("cucumber");

class CustomWorld {
  constructor() {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.browser = browser;
    this.setDefaultTimeout = setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
  }
}

setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld);
```

Comment: I don't use Cucumber but in other frameworks `*all` blocks have different `this` context rather than test blocks because test context is created for each test while `*all` are evaluated once. The reference confirms that. *World is an isolated context for each scenario, exposed to the hooks and steps as this*. You likely should set up and close `browser` for each test.

Answer (score 1):

In a **JS** closure `this` is implicitly set to whatever the outer context is (usually global). You either need to `.bind()` your function to `this` or use the fat array notation:

```
AfterAll(async () => {
  await this.browser.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [CucumberJS docs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md):

> Unlike Before / After these methods will not have a world instance as this. This is because each scenario gets its own world instance and these hooks run before / after all scenarios.

It's unfortunate, as I've ran into this as well. My workaround thus far has been to declare the variable in a scope available to the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` hooks, and then import and assign that to the world object in it's file.